# Plotting input and output signals of a servomechanism using MATLAB

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, graphing-functions, matlab, control-theory

I have the servomechanism system illustrated below.

[image: servo]

The input is voltage $V$ and the output is angle $\theta_L$. How can I plot $V(t)$ and $\theta_L(t)$ in MATLAB?

The equations of the system is shown below.
$$\dot{\omega}_L=-512θ_L-25θ_M-10\omega_L$$
$$\dot{\omega}_M=V-10\omega_M-128θ_L-6θ_M $$
$$$$

Hence,

$$ \theta_L''=-512\theta_L+25\theta_M-10\theta_L' $$
$$\theta''_M=V-10\theta'_M+128\theta_L-6\theta_M $$

Comment: Is your question about how to simulate that differential equation in MATLAB?

Comment: Yes, I want to show the change of $V$ according to time and change of $\theta_L$ according to time. In other words I want to plot $V(t)$ and $\theta_L(t)$ graphs.

Comment: But $V(t)$ is given?

Comment: $V= \theta''_M+10\theta'_M-128\theta'_L+6\theta_M$ value of $V$ changes according to this equation but the problem I do not understand is how can I plot that change? Am I missing something that you pointed out I did not understand. @KwinvanderVeen

Comment: But how would you then define $\theta''_M$. Namely $\theta_M$ and $\theta'_M$ can be found by integrating $\theta'_M$ and $\theta''_M$ respectively over time. Also you added the tag nonlinear-system to this question, but your system is linear (and time invariant).

Comment: I edited the question, thank you for your comment. @KwinvanderVeen

Comment: Find a state space realization $\dot x = A x + b u$ and use **state feedback** $u = -k^\top x$. Use the matrix exponential to find a closed form solution of $\dot x = (A - b k^\top) x$.

Comment: How can I do that? Can you give more details please? @RodrigodeAzevedo

Comment: Find the Jordan decomposition of $A - b k^\top$.

Comment: I already know the Jordan decomposition of the system, I added to the question. How can I plot the input and output signals using that? @RodrigodeAzevedo

Comment: If you only need the plots and do not care about the closed form solutions, then you can solve $\dot x = (A - b k^\top) x$ numerically using, say, MATLAB's [`ode45`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode45.html).

Comment: I understand state space realization but I did not understand state feedback part that you wrote $u=-k^Tx$ So, in that case how how can I solve $\dot{x}=(A-bk^T)x$

Comment: What is $k^T$ in state feedback part? $u=-k^Tx$

Comment: I don't know either. The feedback law you mentioned in a previous comment does not look right.

Comment: You wrote that equation. What is **state feedback**  that you mentioned above?